# my text adventure wont print [python]

Tags: python, text

So, i'm new to python and semi-new to coding in general and I am having a difficult time with simply getting my variable to print.

```
#startup
startup = "welcome to 'da spoopy house', type 'start'"
work = raw_input(startup)

<here is full code>
#functions


#keywords
varlook = "look"
vargo = "go"
varhouse = "house"


#story
st01 = "You are outside, its dusk. there is a house in front of you. both you and the house are surrounded by a forest"
st02 = "You walk up to the house, you notice a small yard with flowers lining the perimeter. As you step up to the door, you notice a small note attached to the door"


#instructions... ?


#action
print st01
raw_input()

if varlook in work:
    print "%s" % st01
    raw_input()

if raw_input == ("%s to %s") % (vargo, varhouse):
    print "%s" % st02
    raw_input()
```

the problem is here

```
#action
print st01
raw_input()

if varlook in work:
    print "%s" % st01
    raw_input()

if raw_input == ("%s to %s") % (vargo, varhouse):
    print "%s" % st02
    raw_input()
```

when I type the desired keyword(s) it simply stops the program, bringing me back to the idle.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to call `raw_input` in `if raw_input == ("%s to %s")`

Comment: You will need to add a loop somewhere. Without it your script will reach the end and terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the misconception that a call to the function `raw_input`, i.e. issueing `raw_input()` will assign the input string to a variable with the name `raw_input`.

In fact, what happens is that the function call **returns** a string, with which you currently do nothing - the string will be garbage collected and lost because you don't have any reference to it.

Assign a variable to the return value, then use the variable in the following code.

Demo:

```
>>> user_input = raw_input()
hello Emmma!
>>> print user_input
hello Emmma!
```